how to query termux wakelock
I'm currently developing a small application for temporarily monitoring sensors in c, that should initiate a wakelock and release it after it ran but not release it, if a wakelock was aquired before execution.
essentially this is my goal:
was wake lock present before the application was executed?

ignore it

wasn't it present before the application was executed?

obtain and clear it throughout the lifetime of this application


when running termux-notification-list, I can check if a wakelock is currently present by searching through it's output until I find this:
{
    "id": 1337,
    "tag": "",
    "key": "0|com.termux|1337|null|10179",
    "group": "",
    "packageName": "com.termux",
    "title": "Termux",
    "content": "1 session (wake lock held)",
    "when": "2024-11-04 15:14:24"
}

is there a better way to figure out if a wakelock is currently in place?
I consider querying notifications a bad idea, as notifications can be discarded even if they are permanent.

Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, [so] is the correct site.
